# Echo the characters /> with php

Tags: php

Im trying to do this:

```
echo '<img src="'. $img_file .'" ' . $imgDem . ' /><br />';
```

but it comes out like this:

```
<img src="/images/content/user/3/127.jpg" height="451" width="804"><br>
```

how can i get it to come out like:

```
<img src="/images/content/user/3/127.jpg" height="451" width="804" /><br />
```

Comment: Are you sure it's printing out this? I think your browser (developer tool) is fooling you.

Comment: What browser do you see it in like that?

Answer (score 7):

PHP won't strip characters from the output, unless you're using some kind of output filter. Most likely whatever you're viewing the HTML in is doing the stripping - Firebug will, for one. Try a plain 'view source' view instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you view the page source. It's displayed with the `\>`.
Are you viewing this from firebug or inspect element from chrome?